# Authenticating Multipart ajax request before file uploading starts

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, servlet-filters, java-ee-7

I am uploading files to a java servlet via ajax. I need to authenticate the upload request before the uploading starts.

I added my Authentication Token before sending the request like (AJAX)

```
beforeSend: function(request) { request.setRequestHeader("tokenName", "tokenData");
},
```

and received it in the servlet-filter like

```
String tokenData=httpRequest.getHeader("tokenName");
```

This works fine until the token is valid.Now when i am uploading a large file say 512MB the browser start uploading and before it has finished uploading I am already checking the authentication token on the servlet side and if it is an invalid token I return a JSON ERROR which results in net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on CHROME and does not display the JSON response that i have sent .

How can i avoid the net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET or check the token before the uploading starts .

Comment: So you check token before the file uploading begins,even for a large file,are you checking after certain time intervals as well or how exactly?